# How to hide a part of ribbon bar?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, ribbon, view-styles

I have a start page with some views of normal and promoted links list. In these displayes I turned off the toolbars. But on the starter page ribbon, the list toolbar appear if a list item is selected in any display.
I tried to use this solution in a script editor (see the code below) but this one turn off the whole ribbon but I wanna turn off just a part of it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("s4-ribbonrow").style.display = "none";
</script>
```

Would anyone help me to solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer below css:

1. To hide list tab:

   .ms-cui-ct-last {
     display: none;
   }
2. To hide item tab:

   .ms-cui-ct-first {
     display: none;
   }

Comment: How can I hide Item tab?

Comment: I have added the css for it.

Comment: @LazloKun Pleasure ;)